# Winform app; execute buttons on start

Tags: winforms, loops, button

Maybe be a stupid question but say i have an Winform App with 2 clickable buttons (button_1 and button_2), each containing a piece of code. If I open the app, I want to click button_1 then button_2, and close the application. What i am wandering is there any way to insert a method that will call button_1 then button_2 on load (and possibly close the app?) that could be inserted into say Form1_Load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't "click the buttons" automatically.  Invoke the logical actions which the buttons invoke automatically.  If that logic is currently in the buttons' click events in the code-behind, refactor it into a common location.

For example, your click event might end up with something like:

```
protected void Button1_Click()
{
    SomeObject.DoSomething();
}
```

Then you can invoke the same action from the form's load event:

```
protected void Form_Load()
{
    SomeObject.DoSomething();
}
```

Following that, still in the form load event, you can then close the application as well:

```
protected void Form_Load()
{
    SomeObject.DoSomething();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Though it seems *really* unnecessary to load up an entire form just to do something without user interaction and then exit.  A console application would be much simpler:

```
static void Main()
{
    SomeObject.DoSomething();
}
```

Then you don't have a UI to worry about, you don't have to attach code to events, you don't even have to forcibly close the application.  It'll just execute the code and exit.

Comment: Just to make sure i got that correct, i could take the code behind the buttons, put it into an  object/method (lets say Calculate, StoreData)  outside the form_Load, and then call those methods/objects in Form_Load?

Comment: @user3645030: Correct.  The overall idea is to separate the UI logic from the business logic.  What the application *does* is business logic, the clickable elements which allow a user to invoke those actions are UI logic.